# Can't solve FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: Error Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple renaming script I'm running in a test directory. It works fine for the first replace method but throws an error on the second use of the method. Can anyone help me solve this one?

```
dir = ('C://Users//zstanley//OneDrive - Golden Gate National Parks Conservancy//BolinasWyeWetlands')
os.chdir(dir)
[os.rename(os.path.join(dir, f), os.path.join(dir, f).replace('_', '').replace(' ', '').lower()) 
    for f in os.listdir(dir)]
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: It can be because of white-spaces in `dir`. You might want to escape them. And please don't use variable names same as built-in functions (such as `dir`).

Comment: `list comprehension` is good. it makes code clean. however, when the list comprehension becomes lengthy, it actually makes the code hard to read and more error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (with `\\` for windows):

Modifications:

1. remove the list comprehension (because it was a bit too long).
2. remove `os.chdir(dir)`, no need to change directory.

I was then able to easily inspect each file and run on a test folder.

```py
import os

dir = ("C:\\test")

# check that the folder exists
if os.path.isdir(dir):
    print('folder exists')
else:
    print('folder does not exist')
    exit()

for f in os.listdir(dir):

    a = os.path.join(dir, f)
    b = os.path.join(dir, f).replace('_', '').replace(' ', '').lower()
    os.rename(a, b)
    print('file names updated')
```

Here are the results:

file system before:

[image]

file system after:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @D.L. Getting this error now: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\zstanley\\OneDrive - Golden Gate National Parks Conservancy\\BolinasWyeWetlands\\admin' -> 'c:\\users\\zstanley\\onedrive-goldengatenationalparksconservancy\\bolinaswyewetlands\\admin'
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(33): Subprocess for 'conda run ['python', 'c:/Users/zstanley/OneDrive - Golden Gate National Parks Conservancy/__Scripts/renaming/renameFolders copy.py']' command failed. Seems to hang up on first folder in directory.

Comment: whiich operating system are you using ?  the code i gave is for windows which uses `\\` to separate the path, `linux` is `/` or alternatively, to be ubiquotous across all operating systems one can use `path.join()` for each directory....

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: there error message tells us that **the folder does not exist** . I know the code works (because i have tested it) so i expect that you might have a typo. Therefore, i have added *an extra part* to validate if the folder exists !!

Comment: Thank you - the first IF statement seems to work but it still seems to be hung up on the admin directory: folder exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\zstanley\OneDrive - Golden Gate National Parks Conservancy\__Scripts\renaming\renameFolders copy.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.rename(old, new)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\zstanley\\OneDrive - Golden Gate National Parks Conservancy\\BolinasWyeWetlands\\admin' -> 'c:\\users\\zstanley\\onedrive-goldengatenationalparksconservancy\\bolinaswyewetlands\\admin'

Comment: the error message is telling you that the folder does not exist.  does it ?  or do you have access to it ?  (i notice in the path that it is oneDrive).  password or locked access ?

Comment: It does exist and I definitely have access to it. I created it. I tried deleting it and it does the same thing with the next folder in the directory...I will recreate this directory on C:\ and check the results.

Comment: i made a `test` folder on the `c:` with dummy files and it works.  Start with replicating that !!

Comment: Works perfectly on C:\. I will explore how to run on One Drive. **THANK YOU**